# What are the key steps in resetting a mac development environment for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, installation, development-environment

Recently I was forced to go back to an old computer for my rails development, where the environment is unfortunately totally messed up.  It's got a ton of legacy stuff on there, so now I'm unable to install a bunch of gems, brew doctor has a slew of warnings, etc.

I'd like to basically just take it from the top and reset the development environment from scratch... is there any way to do this short of a full re-install of the operating system?

Thank you!

Comment: Honestly, if it's that old and full of cruft you're probably better off cleaning things up at a very low level *anyway*.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [RVM](https://rvm.io/), [Jewelry Box](https://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com/) or both, which allow you to manage and easily switch independent Ruby environments (JRuby, MRI/CRuby, Rubinius...) and also have different gem sets.

You can install a completely separate environment from the system’s one in your home directory (which is the default and it will be stored in `~/.rvm`).

The two sites mentioned above have great documentation and installing them is a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both `~/.rvm` and  `~/.gem` can go. Also anything that refers to rvm and gems should be removed. For example, I have `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin` in my `~/.bashrc`. I would remove the line as well before starting clean installation.

You might want to use RVM to carry that out. For that, follow instructions here [Installing RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install). Make sure you get the stable version of RVM and run `rvm requirements`.